# How to Render Current User into Nav-Bar Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Running:

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.2.5
```

I want to render the current user name into the nav-bar button using the dropdown-menu class. I would like to replace "Account Info" with "Hi "current_user".

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account Info <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: "fa fa-pencil-square-o" %></li>
          <li> <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "fa fa-sign-out" %></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class = "nav pull-right">
     </ul>
        <% else %>
         <!-- <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path,  class: "fa fa-sign-in" %> -->
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path, class: "fa fa-sign-in" %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

I'm using devise (3.5.3) for user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to use an if statement to work out if the user is signed_in (I presume this method exists in Devise) and show a different button if the user is signed in:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <% if signed_in? %> 
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Hi, <%= current_user.user_name %> <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <% else %>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account Info <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <% end %>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li> <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: "fa fa-pencil-square-o" %></li>
      <li> <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "fa fa-sign-out" %></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class = "nav pull-right">
 </ul>
    <% else %>
     <!-- <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path,  class: "fa fa-sign-in" %> -->
      <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path, class: "fa fa-sign-in" %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

You'll probably want to use a similar `if, else, end` statement to hide the sign_in/sign_up buttons when the current_user is signed_in too - as they won't want to see that.

Answer (score 0):

This would suffice in your design simply.

```
<%- if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= current_user.user_name %>
<% end %>
```

You have to first ask if the user exists. The reason why is because if you run `.user_name` on a user who is not logged in it is essentially running a method on a nil value. Which is a big no no.

Now if you still have an issue you have to make sure you have this in your controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: which controller should I place `before_filter :authenticate_user!`? In the application controller or should I have a users controller?

Comment: @M.TDavis this should go in the controller that is rendering this view. Since this file seems like a layout file this is likely supposed to be in application controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= content_tag :li, class: "dropdown" %>
   <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= link_to "Hi, #{current_user}", "#", data: {toggle: "dropdown"}, role: :button, aria: {haspopup: "true", expanded: "false"}  %>
      <%= content_tag :ul, class: "dropdown-menu" do %>
         <%= content_tag :li, link_to("Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: "fa fa-pencil-square-o") %>
         <%= content_tag :li, link_to("Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "fa fa-sign-out") %>
      <% end %>
   <% else %>
      <%= content_tag :li, link_to("Sign in", new_user_session_path, class: "fa fa-sign-in") %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Refs:

- [`content_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)

Answer (score 0):

With some testing `<%= current_user.first_name %>` in `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Hi, <%= current_user.first_name %> <span class="caret"></span></a>` seem to give me the outcome I was looking for. Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction. @Alain-Goldman.